# Windows 7 still shows certificate as valid after deleting from cert store

Tags: certificate, windows

I am toying around with self-signed certificates for TLS (closed network). I temporarily added one to my Trusted Root Certification Authorities store on Windows 7, and then verified that it showed as trusted when I double clicked it or used chrome to visit a site using the cert.

When I deleted the cert from the cert store, I expected it to show it as untrusted again. However, it still appears that Windows trusts the cert, even after a reboot. What gives?

Comment: Did you remove it from both the machine's certifcate store and the user's certificate store? if you installed it to the machine's certificate store it would have also been automatically to the user's store.

Comment: Did you remove the certificate [this way](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/how-to-remove-a-root-certificate/)?

Comment: @Ramhound That was it. The cert was still installed in the user store. I removed it and now it is untrusted as I expect. Thanks!